# Человек, рождённый(,) чтобы жить

Tags: пунктуация

Терзаемо существо моё таким предложением:

*Человек, рождённый(,) чтобы жить*

Нужна ли запятая после **"рождённый"**?

Можно сказать по-другому:

*Человек, чтобы жить рождённый*

В этом варианте мне запятую поставить как-то уже меньше хочется. Однако, если сказать нечто в роде

*Человек, рождённый чтобы жить этой женщиной...*

напрашивается, что запятая нужна, так как есть разница между

*Человек, рождённый, чтобы жить, этой женщиной...*

=

*Человека родила эта женщина, чтоб он жил*

и

*Человек, рождённый чтобы жить этой женщиной...*

=

*Человек родился, чтобы жить этой женщиной*

Хотя последние два тоже, наверное, должно обособляться типа

*Человек, рождённый, чтобы жить этой женщиной...*

Что думается, господа?

Comment: `Человек, чтобы жить(,) рождённый` — похоже на инверсию для возвышенности слога или чтобы влезло в стихотворный размер. Так что тут вопрос влияния литературных приемов на правила пунктуации.

Comment: То есть можно и со второй запятой,  и без, если учитывать поэтически-аристократические склад письма?

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а вас интересует грамматика,  реальный смысл и область применения ваших фраз. В русском языке смысловая и коммуникативная сторона текста обязательно учитывается при постановке знаков препинания. Не имеет смысла разбирать ИСКУССТВЕННО ПОСТРОЕННЫЕ конструкции,  в том числе с точки зрения пунктуации. А вы как считаете? Спасибо.

Comment: Абсолютно не вижу какую-либо необходимость наличия обоснованного применения предложений, чтобы копаться в пунктуации. Я могу обыкновенным образом заинтересоваться русским языком и в произвольный час, моя посуду, например, выдумать такой контекст, в грамматической составляющей которого засомневаюсь. Как здесь. Если мне когда-нибудь потребуется сказать нечто такое, я уже буду знать, где расставлять запятые. То же самое с, например, непреднамеренным вопросом о том, как будет выглядеть форма слова "мзда" во множественном числе родительного падежа.

Comment: Я даже не знаю, что оно означает. Меня спросят - не смогу объяснить. Знаю только, что такое слово есть, женский род, возможно связано с деньгами, кредитами и т.д. Но меня заинтересовало, я залез в викисловарь. Там написано под звездочкой **мзд** и меня **АБСОЛЮТНО** это устраивает, несмотря на мнения некоторых, что это неправильно. Я захотел - я выяснил, все, а поводов применения может как не быть сейчас, так и не быть никогда в будущем.

Comment: Зачем говорить о правильности знаков пунктуации, если  предложение не имеет смысла, построено неверно  и нигде не применяется в таком виде. Его просто нет в языке. Эти знания вам никогда не пригодятся, и  правильного ответа они тоже не имеют. Каждая реальная фраза, даже если вы ее сотавляете сами, должна отвечать следующим требованиям: что говорится, кому говорится и с какой целью говорится. Это новый коммуникативный подход к изучению языка,  всегда нужно представлять ситуацию и контекст. Если вы любите язык, то, возможно, попробуете меня услышать.

Comment: Смысл имеет абсолютно все и ничто одновременно. Определяется это лишь углом взгляда. Построено неверно? Хорошо. Нигде не применяется? Замечательно! Моя подача тогда будет уникальна. То, что есть в языке, определяется на нём говорящими. Значит, на какой-то процент это в языке уже есть, раз я затронул тему. Эти знания мне уже пригодились. Если я - Архитектор фразы, то я и определяю, каким требованиям она должна отвечать. Я вижу так, как видеть мне дано. Я учу не ради кого-то, и чтобы кого-то это устраивало, я учу для себя. Роль играема контекстом была если бы, его предоставил бы я.

Comment: Теперь вы мне даже нравитесь! У вас здесь другая реальность, да? Как бы такая игра. Но я же не знала, думала, что здесь всё по-настоящему.  А остальные-то отвечающие на ваши вопросы об этом знают?  Но вот  вы утверждаете, что ваш вопрос неслучаен, и это наводит на определенные мысли. За влияние чужой лексики на русский язык в новом информационном пространстве  я не очень беспокоюсь – мы всегда брали у других лучшее, оставляли ненужное и становились при языковых контактах только сильнее.

Comment: Но грамматика,  система русского письма (тонкие материи!) – вот что меня беспокоит. Знаете, понять внутренний строй русской речи дано далеко не каждому – легче построить несколько собственных языков.  Но, может быть, именно это защитит нашу грамматику от внешнего воздействия и от «новых архитектурных форм». Что ж,  определенную информацию о «ментальном климате» и  состоянии здешних умов я все-таки  получила, и на том спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

1 Человек, рождённый, чтобы жить. Запятая нужна.причастный оборот включает придаточное цели с союзом "чтобы".

2 Человек, чтобы жить рождённый. Можно и так, но только первый вариант лучше, причастие обычно ставят после существительного, к которому оно относится. Смысл здесь: Человек, рожденный для жизни.

3 Человек, рождённый, чтобы жить, этой женщиной... Лучше: Человек, рожденный этой женщиной (для жизни), чтобы жить.

Если запятых нет, то смысл меняется.  Чтобы жить этой женщиной.(смысл либо, жить ради неё, либо родился женщиной). Но перед "чтобы" запятая сохраняется.

То есть всегда выделяется причастный оборот, если он стоит после существительного, каким бы сложным и распространенным он ни был. И от перестановки и пропуска знаков препинания смысл может измениться.

Comment: 1) а выходит что ли так, что **Человек, рождённый, чтобы жить** - обособляется дважды, а **Человек, чтобы жить рожденный** в двойном обрсоблении не нуждается? Можно ли даже при такой перестановке "впихнуть" обе запятые - **Человек, чтобы жить, рожденный**? 2)Вы говорите, что причастный оборот, после существительного стоящий, всегда выделяется, а как же **Я увидел человека рождённого** - Неужели даже здесь запятая нужна? Сомнений насчёт **Я увидел человека, в полночь рождённого** или **Я увидел рождённого в полночь человека** нет, а если в одно слово после существительного? Тоже же причастие...

Comment: 1 да , но чтобы жить рожденный уже не разделяется, как для жизни рожденный.2 причастный оборот-- это не единичное причастие, а причастие с зависимыми словами , поэтому не нужна.

Comment: Не совсем понял про **1)** - "да" - это к "а выходит что ли так, что.. " или к "можно ли ... "впихнуть" обе запятые"? 2) Тогда зависимым словом выступает абсолютно всё?  **Человек, рождённый там** или **Человек, рождённый быстро**, или **Человек, рождённый вчера** и т.д.

Comment: 1) Да -- к вашему номеру 1,  2) что такое "абсолютно всё"? Междометия не входят, например. Я на абстрактные вопросы ответить не могу, только на конкретные. Погуглите про причастный оборот.

Comment: А если я всё же поставлю запятую в случае **Человек, чтобы жить, рождённый** это будет расцениваться как стопроцентная ошибка или вполне может сойти за авторскую пунктуацию, что можно наблюдать в различных произведениях? 2) Я имел в виду всё, что логически можно подставить к **рождённый**: "там", "быстро", "вчера" и т.д.  Здесь и наречие, и обстоятельство двух категорий, и наверняка ещё можно что-нибудь всунуть, и будет также считаться зависимым словом.

Comment: Ошибка. Придаточное относится не к существительному "человек", а к причастию.

Comment: Буду ли я прав в предположении, что, если порядок прямой - **Человек, рождённый, чтобы жить**, поводов для запятой два: перед причастием и перед подчинительным союзом, а, если порядок извилистый - **Человек, чтобы жить рождённый**, одна и та же запятая отыгрывает эти же обе роли, но запятая одна, так как запятая для **чтобы** совпадает по месту расположения с запятой для **рождённый**?

Comment: Ну конечно, первая запятая отделяет определяемое существительное от причастного оборота (в обоих случаях)

Answer (score 0):

Попробую ответить проще и откровеннее, дипломатия здесь вроде бы не приветствуется и только мешает.

Человек, рождённый(,) чтобы жить. Это предложение? Нет, конечно, в нем нет предикативной основы. Это назывная конструкция, распространенное словосочетание, к тому же построенное не лучшим образом.

- А как же причастие "рожденный" в роли сказуемого?
- Ну что вы! Разве может быть сказуемым обособленный член предложения? К тому же полная форма причастий вообще редко бывает сказуемым, для этого есть краткая форма: Человек рожден, чтобы жить.
- А почему полное причастие редко бывает сказуемым?
- Если полное причастие стоит сразу после подлежащего, то его функцию трудно определить. В такое позиции может находиться определение с претензиями на смысловой центр высказывания. В языке все разумно, у каждой формы слова своя роль. В принципе полная форма причастия может быть сказуемым, но это особые случаи, например: Это только что написанная книга, ее еще не отдавали в печать.
- А  остальные фразы?
- А все остальные фразы лишены смысла и построены с нарушением всех возможных норм, которые вообще существуют, то есть грамматических, структурно-интонационных, стилистических и коммуникативных. И что удивительно, в этих фразах автор просит проверить знаки препиания.